# Display message box only if "filter finder items" finds an item (Automator)

Tags: macos, mac, finder, applescript, automator

Currently, I have a workflow going like this:

```
When files and folders added to downloads
Filter finder items where kind = music
Open finder items with ID3 tag editor
Ask for confirmation "Click OK when tags edited"
Filter finder items where kind = music (for safety)
Move finder items to "Itunes Autoadd" folder
```

However, even when I download a file that is not music (".dmg" file) the messagebox will still display.

How do I make it so the messagebox only displays when a music file is found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing the right thing.

There is no decision making being done so the dialog box will appear every time. To fix it, you will need to add an AppleScript action as discussed here

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/509298?start=0&tstart=0

So, if the filter returns an empty list `{}` then it quits.

Here is what it looks like...

[image: Folder Action that exits early]

Comment: You just saved me so many unnecessary clicks. THANK YOU!